# Using a change of variable to reduce a linear 2nd-order PDE to a 1st-order PDE

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, change-of-variable

I created the following example, but am unsure if my final answer is correct or in the nicest possible form. (My study materials' examples don't involve the mixed partial, and none have the integral sign in their final answers as I do below.) $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are arbitrary functions.

[image]

Comment: Please include the title and author(s) of your textbook for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @hardmath I was actually working off a slim set of lecture notes rather than a textbook, creating much of my own from scratch. Does the solution, with that indefinite integral, look okay, btw?

Comment: Your result $u(x,y)$ is correct. No simpler form if no boundary condition is specified.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiating the final result:
\begin{align}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&=-4x+\sqrt{x}\phi_1(4x+y^2)\\
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y\partial x}&=2y\sqrt{x}\left[\phi_1'(z)\right]_{z=4x+y^2}\\
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}&=-4+\frac1{2\sqrt x}\phi_1(4x+y^2)+4\sqrt{x}\left[\phi_1'(z)\right]_{z=4x+y^2}
\end{align}
Plugging the above into the given PDE gives $-2=-2;$ therefore, that final result is indeed a solution to the PDE.

According to jjacquelin (in a comment above), this solution has no simpler form unless some boundary condition is specified.